# Fatal error class not found despite having declared the class

Tags: php, class, compiler-errors

For all my files I require `framework.php` which calls `config.php` as such:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.php');
```

**`config.php` calls:**

```
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'array.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'dir.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'security.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'user.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'forms.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'tables.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR . 'string.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'tags.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'backup.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'image.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'automate.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'stats.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'messages.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'nemesis.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'upload.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'timezone.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'media_resource.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once(CLASSES_DIR . 'google_analytics_api.php');
require_once(TEMPLATES_DIR . 'construct.php');
require_once(LIBS_DIR . 'prepared_arrays.php');
require_once('AS.php');
```

**`AS.php` calls:**

```
require_once 'ASConfig.php';
require_once 'ASSession.php';
require_once 'ASValidator.php';
require_once 'ASLang.php';
require_once 'ASRole.php';
require_once 'ASDatabase.php';
require_once 'ASEmail.php';
require_once 'ASLogin.php';
require_once 'ASRegister.php';
require_once 'ASUser.php';

$db = ASDatabase::getInstance();

ASSession::startSession();

$login    = new ASLogin();
$register = new ASRegister();
$mailer   = new ASEmail();

$user = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
$userInfo = $user->getInfo();

if ( isset ( $_GET['lang'] ) )
    ASLang::setLanguage($_GET['lang']);
```

However, in a function of `class ASUsers` I do:

```
public function deleteUser() {
        $userProfilePicture = new Images($this->userId);
        $userProfilePicture->deleteProfilePicture(false);
        $this->db->delete("as_users", "user_id = :id", array( "id" => $this->userId ));
        $this->db->delete("as_user_details","user_id = :id", array( "id" => $this->userId ));
        //$this->db->delete("as_comments","posted_by = :id", array( "id" => $this->userId ));
        $this->db->delete("as_social_logins","user_id = :id", array( "id" => $this->userId ));
}
```

However I am getting a fatal error, class Images not found.

What am I doing wrong?

*UPDATE*

Moving the requires of AS.php into config.php and the scripts in AS.php into framework.php seems to fix the issue. Not sure why.

Comment: you are requiring image.php from config.php, have you also required config.php?

Comment: you have to include/require `image.php` in `ASUsers` class. Please try that and let us know.

Comment: Actually you have to write  `include_once (config.php)` in your present code. Or if you included `config.php` in `framework.php` then write `include_once (framework.php)`. I am telling this based on your first three sentences. I am not able to see include of framework.php in your pasted code.

Comment: @Chris Yes: "I require framework.php which calls config.php"

Comment: @Anant i've updated with more code!

Comment: @LeaTano but that's the issue... i've already required it BEFORE `AS.php` which requires `ASUsers.php` which houses the function where the issue lies.

Comment: The problem is the scope. However; why are you not using autoload? You will only need to include your autoload.php?

Comment: I don't get it because in say automate for example I use images in a similar fashion and it works

Comment: Is AS.php in the same folder lever than config.php and framework.php? Did you see in your error log any warning before the fatal error, like PATH/framework.php file not found?

Comment: Different folder level. And no error. It's called correctly